# SQL Server : same CONVERT statement has to use different styles on servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I tried to execute the below code snippet on two different machines. Both of them have SQL Server 2012 installed and both collations are `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Interestingly on one of the machines the style parameter for `CONVERT` function needs to be set to 103 otherwise I get

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

whereas on the other machine, I have to use style 101 otherwise I will get that same error.

I did some googling and I suspected this behavior somewhat relates to the system locale and language settings but I could be wrong.

Code snippet:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime2(0), LEFT(name, 11) + '' + replace(convert(char(5), cast(replace(RIGHT(LEFT(name, 22), 10), '.', '') as datetime), 108), ':', ':'), 101)
FROM 
    #FileList
```

Sample rows from #FileList:

```
01/12/2016  03:27 p.m.           610,304 0.mdb
30/05/2014  07:43 p.m.           438,274 1.mdb
03/06/2014  02:52 a.m.        14,921,730 10.mdb
31/05/2014  10:35 a.m.        11,120,642 12.mdb
31/05/2014  01:52 a.m.           438,274 13.mdb
```

This is how `#FileList` gets built:

```
SET @cmd = 'dir '+@DirectoryPath+'*.mdb /b'
INSERT INTO #FileList
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it is the `DIR` command that returns the dates in different format on the different servers. And the DIR command displays the dates in the format defined in your Regional settings. Show us the result of the DIR command from both servers

Comment: @cha you are right. I compared the results returned from the dir command and they are in different formats. However on the same machine the DIR command executed from SQL Server Management Studio gives MM/DD/YYYY format but DD/MM/YYYY from CMD. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: The DIR command runs under the user that started the SQL Service. You need to change the Regional settings for this user in the Registry